# How to store honey so it's fresh and the opening of the container is not always a mess?

Tags: storage-method, honey

How to store honey so it's fresh and the opening of the container is not always a mess? The plastic container the honey comes in has a small opening for squeezing, but it is always a mess.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16696/what-is-the-best-temperature-to-store-honey-at

Comment: Do you have one of those containers that have a hole that is covered with a kind if a "valve", that opens when you squeeze the bottle?

Comment: That was obviously what I meant by "a small opening for squeezing."

Comment: @qazwsx no need to be rude; a small opening (hole) may or may not have a valve on it, so clarification is helpful.

Comment: It's this kind of opening: https://www.amazon.com/Desert-Creek-Honey-Unfiltered-Unpasteurized/dp/B00Q33NM12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honey by its very nature is sticky and will stick to any surface it will touch. If wiping away the excess honey from a container with a small hole for squeezing is not something you want to have to do, you may want to consider procuring yourself another kind of airtight container.

If being able to squeeze honey out is important, a lid with a rubber valve like below may be suitable for you. The valve opens as you squeeze the bottle and closes itself on its own when you stop squeezing, preventing the honey from accumulating too much. It works better than a plain hole, but may need occasional cleaning.

[image: Lid with rubber valve]

If cleanliness is more important than squeezability, a glass jar may be the way to go for you. A wide enough opening will allow you to scoop the honey out with a spoon or [a honey dipper](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32241/how-to-use-a-honey-dipper) without it gunking anything up, though you'll need to be careful not to drip too much on your way out, or the lid will become sticky as well.

Comment: I am going to buy a glass jar with metal cap.

Answer (score 5):

There are a variety of storage containers that can keep honey fresh, [as long as the container is airtight](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/16696/17272). When I buy local honey in jars, I leave it in there; if I buy a squeezable container with a small dispensing hole, I leave it in there.

The key to avoiding sticky buildup (which frequently makes it difficult to open the jar or bottle, beyond just being icky) is to **wipe down the container after dispensing honey.** A damp cloth or damp paper towel, or even a slightly damp forefinger, is sufficient to remove the small amount of honey residue and leave the container clean for storage.

Comment: A messy dispensing hole on my honey container is like a stuffy nose for me; I'm not satisfied enough to always have to wipe it. What is a thorough solution?

Comment: A stuffy nose requires frequent wiping to breathe properly. Surely you don't use honey multiple times a day making a quick wipe inconvenient. Every time I have a drink of juice or tea, I have to wash the cup. I don't consider it inconvenient to do so. I view wiping the lid of honey the same.